# "Double Clicking" or Enter on selected file in windows explorer

Tags: python, windows, popen, explorer

I'm trying to simulate "double click" or enter on a selected file in windows explorer (win10pro) after I've run this code:

```
import subprocess
os.chdir("C:/Users/***/***/DeforumStableDiffusionLocal")
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select, "C:\Users\***\***\DeforumStableDiffusionLocal\run_still.bat')
```

I've tried importing the keyboard module but I'm a little confused as to how it would interact with the opened explorer window.
Normally i would run within python, but I'm trying to streamline with another program where I'm getting weird SSL errors from within the program, but when run in windows explorer it works fine.   Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In native Windows you would use `ShellExecute`. In Python you should use [`os.startfile(myfilepath)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile).